# How to count days between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

this javascript calculate worng number of the days

i select two dates

1st date 2013-01-01
2nd date 2013-12-31

and it is showing worng answer 365 days

i was calculte manual it is worng correct answer is 364 days

how can i fix this issue please help me
thanks

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BXMv6/3/)**

form

```
<input class='fromdate' />
<input class='todate' />
<input class='calculated' />
<input class='minim' /><br/><p><font size="3"><b>For more FAQs Visit<a  target="_blank"href="http://jqfaq.com/"</a> JQFaq.com</b></font></p>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://jqfaq.com/AdPage.html" style="width:100%; height:115px; border:none;"
/>
```

javascript

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
$('.todate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
$('.fromdate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var minValue = $(this).val();
    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
    $('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
    calculate();
});
$('.todate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var maxValue = $(this).val();
    maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
    $('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
    calculate();
});

function calculate() {
    var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 1;
    if (d1 && d2) {
        diff = diff + Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    }
    $('.calculated').val(diff);
    $('.minim').val(d1)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852949/jquery-datepicker-day-count

Comment: this is not duplicate this questn have another problem

Comment: -1. There are 365 days in 2013. If you want to exclude last date then do not add 1.

Comment: use var diff = 0 instead of var diff = 1. If you initialize diff as 1. Your count will be increase one day. So, initialize diff as 0.

Answer (score 1):

Like this way you can do it -

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,22);

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
```

[Refer this](http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/DaysBetween.asp)

Comment: @user3000993 If you got the solution, please pick this answer as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to calculate the "diff" in function calculate():

```
   if (d1 && d2) {
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
        diff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the var diff=1 is causing problem.

change it to var diff=1 then see you will get 364 days.